# SQL server missing in ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I installed a SQL Express server on a 32-bit Windows 2008 server r2. I installed this while installing a Phoenix fueling station program. When I am trying to add a user DSN in ODBC I am unable to find the SQL server so I can connect it to our Main database. Does anyone have any ideas on how I would be able to find this?

Comment: Did you enable the Named Pipes and TCP connection methods for the SQL server?  Are you using the "SQL Server", or "SQL Server Native Client" driver for your ODBC connection? What exactly did you try already in attempts to connect?

Comment: That was one of the things I did was make sure that both TCP/IP and Named Pipes were enabled. I also tried connecting to It native client but when I try to find the SQL server name its nowhere to be found. The only 2 places I can find this server are in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and the SQL Server Management Studio Express.

Comment: Perhaps better explain how you are trying to "find" the server... I'm assuming you mean letting the ODBC wizard to list the servers to you.  If that's right, what happens when you just enter the connection information directly into the ODBC setup instead of searching for it?

Comment: Excellent, I'll throw it up as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

By "find the server", I'm assuming you mean letting the ODBC wizard to list the servers to you so you can pick.

If it can't display it to you (which is not unusual form my experience), just enter the connection information directly into the ODBC setup instead of searching for it.